# abi.decoder in solidity

Tags: solidity, web3js, abi

Im trying to decode a `bytes memory _data` parameter directly in a smart contract.

Im currently running:

```
var data = await abi.encode("120000000000000000000", user2, OCcontract1.address, "120000000000000000000", OCcontract2);
```

So with its types

```
data abi.encode(BN, address, address,BN, address);
```

now within a function I want to use the solidity equivalent of `abi.decode` but running directly on the smart contract.

Any pointer will really help.

Answer (score 5):

This did the trick for me:

```
functionName(data){
    uint _amount;
    address _receiver;
    address _tokenLeadContract;
    uint _expectedAmount;
    address _expectedSC;
    (_amount, _receiver, _tokenLeadContract, _expectedAmount, _expectedSC) = abi.decode(data, (uint, address, address, uint, address));
 }
```