# How to make use of arbitrary bytes array

Tags: solidity

I'm implementing an ERC-721 contract that supports the function:

```
safeTransferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId, bytes data)
```

The last parameter of this function is an arbitrary byte array. I imagine most implementations of this function ignore this parameter, but I am interested in using it. Specifically, I want to pass two additional `uint256` fields in this parameter and decode them within the contract. How can I achieve this? For example:

```
function safeTransferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId, bytes calldata data) public {
    (uint256 startDate, uint256 endDate) = decode(data);
    // etc...
}
```

In the above example, I'm asking how to implement the `decode` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use abi.decode() function of solidity to extract your uint256 values.

Reference: [abi.decoder in solidity](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/66460/abi-decoder-in-solidity)

First make the bytes data using in the script, or using web3:

```
var data = await abi.encode(11111111,2222222);
```

Then extract those uint256 in solidity:

```
function Name(bytes memory data) public pure returns(uint8 number1, uint256 number2) {
    
        (number1, number2) = abi.decode(data, (uint8, uint256));

    }
```

And this should do the trick!

Comment: glad it helped....

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Solidity Dev worked for me except I had to change the javascript part to:

```
var data = web3.eth.abi.encodeParameters(['uint8','uint256'], [111111, 222222]);
```